# Get Request result 1 time on 4 ( php, Ajax )

Tags: php, ajax

My problem is: 
In localhost : all work fine
In Server : ...
So in local my php script return result all time, but in server i got response 1 time on 5 or never or 2 on 2, it's totally random.

I was thinking the problem was my ajax, so i open the php script and refresh to see result, in local it was perfect php script return result all times, so I upload my code to my server and BOOOM nothing. 
I don't understand why. 
Php don't return error.

```
require_once 'DB.php';

$query = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($row);

?>
```

Actually I don't have result in server, and without any error from php.

Thank you for your help 
;)

Comment: can you explain this "So in local my php script return result all time, but in server i got response 1 time on 5 or never or 2 on 2" its not clear what you are asking here

Comment: if you don't have a lot of users `"SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2"` would be more efficient than the above.

Comment: @Tim Thank you :)

Comment: @Tim When I execute this script in localhost I don't have problem. But in my website the script don't display result all times without error.

Comment: http://mon-cv.pro/php/test.php you can see script her in action. Thank you

Comment: im guessing your server cant reach your localhost database, or is the database on the same server?

Comment: No i use local database in local but in Web server i use online db, at ovh.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find, now it's work :)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
$query =  $bdd->prepare($query);
$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) //outputs the records
{
    echo json_encode($row, 512);
};
?>
```

Thank you so much for your help